# Calculating days since last update in a list column

Tags: list

I am trying to create "Days since last update" calculated column using `DATEDIF([Modified], [Today], "d")` and I am getting the following error: Calculated columns cannot contain volatile functions like Today and Me.

I guess it's not as simple as I thought. Is there any easy ways to accomplish this? I am starting with this and not yet fully understand power aps and everything so i would like to be able to do it in list preferrably.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use below formula to calculate date differece between modfied to current date.

```
=DATEDIF([Modified],TODAY(),"d")
```

- Refer the below output in DateDiffrence column

[image: Date Diffrence]

Comment: Thanks a lot it's exactly what i needed

Comment: after testing it does work but remain static and does not recalculate nor update, is there a way to make it update?

Comment: do you mean after date change it is not reflecting ?